# What do you do if you accidentally joined a tapered drywal edge with a butted drywall edge?

Tags: drywall

I had a rather complicated cut for a piece of drywall that was going in an area around some pipes
I did not pay attention when I did the cutting and I ended up with a butted edge against a tapered edge.
Is there a way to deal with this when I do the taping and the mudding or I need to start over again and cut the piece again?

Comment: The mudding probably will need feathering out to 12 or more inches instead of around 6.  Choice of redoing or doing very good mud job, which you think will be easier.  A bad(not good enough) mud job probably won't show till after painting.

Comment: this is in a basement right in front of an above grade window, parallel with the window. I will probably end up cutting that drywall piece again unless someone gives me a better idea

Comment: Here is another question about same problem with answers.   https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/210623/is-a-butt-edge-to-tapered-edge-drywall-joint-ok?rq=1

Comment: Like any other joint, apply mud, let dry completely. repeat until it looks good...